# How to validate response with variables and regular expression

Tags: karate

I need help to validate a response containing variables and regular expression. In my example below, logFile has the pattern C:\Temp\FileName_20180416_091535.log. I'm trying to using regex for the digits before the extension, but I can't get it to work. I prefer to use it directly in the json without having to define a variable, but so far I can't get it to work either. Is this possible to do and how?

```
Background:  
* def currentDate = '20180416'  
* def filePath = 'C:\\Temp\\'  
* def fileName = 'TestFile1'  

Scenario:  
* def logFile = filePath + fileName + '_' + currentDate + '_' + '#regex[0-9]+' + '.log'  
* def date = currentDate + 'T00:00:00'  
* def resp =  
"""  
{  
    logFile: '#(logFile)',  
    date: '#(date)'  
}  
"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do that concatenation. The rule is the string content of the field should *start* with `#regex`.

This works:

```
* def json = { logFile: 'C:\\Temp\\FileName_20180416_091535.log' }
* match json == { logFile: '#regex [^_]+_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{6}\\.log' }
```

Comment: I want to validate the path, file name and the date part in the file name.  I don't need to validate the seconds in the file name.  How do I do that?  The file name and date will change depending on the tests.  But I can handle that.

Comment: @bhc there are plenty of ways, it doesn't need to be a regex. look at self validation expressions in the doc and use a JS function if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions

Comment: I'm not sure how but the following seems to work for me.   

* def logFile = '#regex ' + filePath + fileName + '_' + currentDate + '_[0-9]+.log'